# Google Sheet Connection to SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am hoping that someone can help me with this connection issue, I am trying to connect a Google Sheet to a SQL Server 2014 database and pull the data via a View.

Below is a piece of code that I have taken from the :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample

```
import java.sql.*;  

public class connectURL {  

   public static void main(String[] args) {  

      // Create a variable for the connection string.  
      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +  
         "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=UserName;password=*****";  

      // Declare the JDBC objects.  
      Connection con = null;  
      Statement stmt = null;  
      ResultSet rs = null;  

      try {  
         // Establish the connection.  
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);  

         // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.  
         String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact";  
         stmt = con.createStatement();  
         rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);  

         // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.  
         while (rs.next()) {  
            System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));  
         }  
      }  

      // Handle any errors that may have occurred.  
      catch (Exception e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
      }  
      finally {  
         if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
         if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
         if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
      }  
   }  
}
```

I have amended the connection string with the relevant SQL connection username and password but I am getting the following error :-

Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")Dismiss

I am very new to this so please if possible keep the answers as simple as possible.

Thanks PD

After some time I cut down the original code and it looks a lot more like what I am after but still having some connection issues, can anyone see what the error might be

```
// Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
function readFromTable() {

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IP ADDRESS:1433;databaseName=name;user=user;password=password");

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM table');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

Comment: Your code sample says "localhost". The Script run on Google Servers so you must use an address that can be reached from the internet and make sure your SQL Server responds to such address.